# What would be the proper way to create a create OR update route on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :metric
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and I would like to create an endpoint to either create OR update a metric, through the Post. I would like to understand what would be the proper HTTP verb to be used, and how to properly create the route. Right now I have the following route:

```
resources :posts, only: [] do
  resources :metrics, only: [:create, :update]
end
```

But that's not really what I'm trying to achieve because to update a metric I need to know the id of the metric.

Thank you.

Comment: if you change `resources :metrics` to `resource :metrics` you remove the `id` from the route... it depends how your UI is designed, but I would probably use nested attributes in that case and only update the post

Comment: This is the basic problem that GraphQL seeks to solve. But as gabrielhilal has suggested: nested attributes is probably the easiest way to solve this issue. You may have to customise the code to handle the create or update scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a route, change the code in POST method like
`metric = Metric.where(field_name: '#{value}').first_or_create` then assign values to metric object.
(or)
`metric = Metric.where(field_name: '#{value}').first_or_initialize`then assign values to metric object.
This will check the metric table for a specific record if found one then `.first` will work and it will update the details else `.initialize` (or) `.create` will work and it will create a new Metric record.